# How to change child fragment imageView from ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, bundle

I have `ViewPager` and 4 fragments in it. Fragment 2 called `StatusFragment`. In that `StatusFragment` I have an `ImageView`. In `ViewPager` I'm getting `bundle` of String, that's an image path. I'm getting my bundle successfully, but now i need to decode my path with bitmap and add it in `ImageView` of `StatusFragment`. I tried to do `ImageView` from `StatusFragment` public, and change it from `ViewPager`, but that gives `NullPointerException`. How can I change that Image from `ViewPager`? Thank you.

Here the ViewPager code.

```
public class SlidePageTabsMainFragment extends BaseFragment {
private View mainView;
private TabLayout mTabs;
private ViewPager mPage;
private FragmentActivity myContext;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
private StatusFragment statusFragment;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_page_tabs_main_fragment, container, false);
    mTabs = (TabLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    mPage = (ViewPager) mainView.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout_id);

    mPage.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

    //mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mPage);
    SetUpViewPager();
    getTabLayoutLocation();
    setmFloatingActionButtons();

    Bundle getBundleImagePath = getArguments();
    if(getBundleImagePath != null){
        String getImagePaths = getBundleImagePath.getString("imagePath");
        Toast.makeText(myContext, getImagePaths, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getImagePaths);
        //statusFragment.photoId.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        mPage.setCurrentItem(1);
    }
    return mainView;
}
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SlidePageTabsMainFragment";
}

public void SetUpViewPager() {
    //Add fragments
    SlidePageTabsAdapter adapter = new SlidePageTabsAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new SupportopFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new StatusFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new ConnectionsFragment());
    adapter.addFragment(new SupportersFragment());

    //Setting adapter
    mPage.setAdapter(adapter);
    mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mPage);

    //Setting icons in tabs
    mTabs.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.supportop_icon);
    mTabs.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.repair_icon);
    mTabs.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.transport_icon);
    mTabs.getTabAt(3).setIcon(R.drawable.security_icon);
    //mPage.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mTabs));

    mPage.addOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    // mTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mPage));

}
}
```

Ok that was a little big code, but I think you understood it.

Now i'll add the StatusFragment.

```
public class StatusFragment extends BaseFragment {

private View mainView;
public ImageView photoId;
private SlidePageTabsMainFragment slidePages;

public StatusFragment() {};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_fragment, container, false);

    photoId = (ImageView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.photo_id);
    slidePages = new SlidePageTabsMainFragment();

    return mainView;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "StatusFragment";
}
}
```

Ok, now when you watched the code, so how can I change `photoId` image from `ViewPager`, if I'm getting the bundle in `ViewPager`? Don't say to get the bundle in `StatusFragment`. I need to get it in `ViewPager` only. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the image path in the view pager itself?

Comment: I have an imageSlider, and from that imageSlider i need to send the selected image path with bundle in viewPager, if I'll send it to fragment directly, the ViewPager will not load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a bundle to your StatusFragment with the Bitmap into it. Bitmap implements Parcelable so it can be stored in a Bundle:

**In SlidePageTabsMainFragment**

```
public void setUpViewPager(Bitmap b) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("image", b);
    //... your code
    // Add arguments to the Fragment
    Fragment statusFragment = new StatusFragment();
    statusFragment.setArguments(args);

    //...   
    adapter.addFragment(statusFragment);
    //...
}
```

**In StatusFragment**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_fragment, container, false);

    photoId = (ImageView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.photo_id);

    // Get the Bitmap and set it to the ImageView
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    Bitmap image = (Bitmap) bundle.getParcelable("image");
    photoId.setImageBitmap(image);

    slidePages = new SlidePageTabsMainFragment();

    return mainView;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try this now. I tried in that bundle create a new Bundle and send it to StatusFragment, and i get that in StatusFragment. But the bundle from statusFragment runs first)

Comment: You need to call `setUpViewPager();` **after** you get the Bitmap in 'SlidePageTabsMainFragment '

Comment: I think my problem was in addAdapter, I created new StatusFragment, but in adapter i done addAdapter(new StatusFragment)

Comment: And yes, remove this line and replace it by the code above

Comment: Thanks man, worked. Please can you vote my question too? I need a little reputation))